# Is it possible to give an Adorner an absolute position or to move it for example a bit more to the left?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, validation, adorner

At the moment I am having the problem that the displayed error goes over several labels or textboxes. I was hoping that I would be able to give the adorner an absolute postion. If that is not possible than I would like to move it to the left. Now I was not able to find useful information on the internet about the positioning of adorners. So I am wondering is there a way to change to position of an adorner?

I am able to paste my code here if it would help to get a solution for the positioning of the adorner.

All help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should derive from the Adorner object, and override location determination logic there, which would allow you to do all kinds of tricks, including absolute / relative positioning.

```
public class ControlAdorner: Adorner
{
    #region Private fields

    // Utilized for caching of offset by x co-ordinate.
    private double m_OffsetX = 0d;

    // Uri    private double m_OffsetY = 0d;
    #endregion

    #region Initialization
    public ControlAdorner( UIElement adornedElement )
        : base( adornedElement )
        {

        }
    #endregion

    #region Implementation
    //Measures content.
    protected override Size MeasureOverride( Size constraint )
    {
        m_child.Measure( constraint );
        return AdornedElement.RenderSize;
    }

    //Arranges child control to the full size.
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride( Size finalSize )
    {
        m_child.Arrange( new Rect( finalSize ) );
        return m_child.RenderSize;
    }

    public override GeneralTransform GetDesiredTransform( GeneralTransform transform )
    {
        GeneralTransformGroup group = new GeneralTransformGroup();
        group.Children.Add( transform );
        group.Children.Add( new TranslateTransform( OffsetX, OffsetY ) );
        return group;
    }

    //Get visual by index.
    protected override Visual GetVisualChild( int index ) 
    {
        return m_child;
    }

    private static void OnOffsetXChanged( DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        ControlAdorner instance = (ControlAdorner)d;
        instance.OnOffsetXChanged( e );
    }

    private void OnOffsetXChanged( DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        m_OffsetX = (double)e.NewValue;
        if( OffsetXChanged != null )
        {
            OffsetXChanged( this, e );
        }
    }

    private static void OnOffsetYChanged( DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        ControlAdorner instance = (ControlAdorner)d;
        instance.OnOffsetYChanged( e );
    }

    private void OnOffsetYChanged( DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        m_OffsetY = (double)e.NewValue;
        if( OffsetYChanged \!= null )
        {
            OffsetYChanged( this, e );
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Events
    public event PropertyChangedCallback OffsetXChanged;
    public event PropertyChangedCallback OffsetYChanged;
    public double OffsetX
    {
        get
        {
            return m_OffsetX;
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue( OffsetXProperty, value );
        }
    }
    public double OffsetY
    {
        get
        {
            return m_OffsetY;
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue( OffsetYProperty, value );
        }
    }

    // Gets visual children count, always 1.
    protected override int VisualChildrenCount
    {
        get
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Dependency properties
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OffsetXProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( 
      "OffsetX", typeof( double ), typeof( ControlAdorner ),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( 0d,    
        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange | 
        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentArrange, 
        new PropertyChangedCallback( OnOffsetXChanged ) ) );

    public static readonly DependencyProperty OffsetYProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( 
      "OffsetY", typeof( double ), typeof( ControlAdorner ),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( 0d, 
        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange |
        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentArrange, 
        new PropertyChangedCallback( OnOffsetYChanged ) ) );
    #endregion
}
```

http://www.artfulbits.com/technologies/winfx/adorners.aspx

Comment: I have used Adorner in my project but the adorner window is not near the mouse pointer. How to change the position of adorner window near the mouse pointer. Please give any suggestion.